# Possible to add AIR2.7 to Flash Pro CS6?

Tags: flash, air

It seems that the only way to debug an AIR app on Kindle Fire is by creating it with AIR2.7. I have Flash Pro CS6, so I downloaded AIR2.7 from Adobe archive and tried to add it through the Manage AIR SDK dialog only to get this error:

> The selected folder does not contain a valid AIR SDK.

Any suggestions?